# About community.to.membership function

Tags: r, igraph

```
library(igraph)
g=graph.famous("Zachary")
c=walktrap.community(g)
a=community.to.membership(g,c$merges,steps=2)
b=a$membership
modularity(g,b)
```

When running the `modularity(g,b)` function, `R` did not respond. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in igraph. The `community.to.membership` function returns a zero-based membership vector and `modularity` expects a 1-based membership vector.

The `community.to.membership` function is actually deprecated and the `cutat` function should be used instead:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(42)
g <- graph.famous("Zachary")
c <- walktrap.community(g)
b <- cutat(c, steps=2)
modularity(g, b)
# [1] -0.02621631
```

Btw. your example is not reproducible, because `walktrap.community` is not deterministic and you don't set the random seed.

Btw.2. there is *no* real difference between igraph versions 0.6-1 and 0.6-3 (and 0.6-x), the number after a dash is just the build number. The package was rebuilt for technical reasons, and version 0.6-3 contains the same code as 0.6-1.

Comment: Thanks! This explaination helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (after updating igraph to 0.6-3), giving

```
> modularity(g,b)
[1] -0.05041913
```

You might try closing R, updating igraph and then rerunning the code.

Comment: Which version of R do you have?  Did you try starting from scratch?

Comment: yes from scratch. R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) ( i tested both platform)

Comment: @agstudy For me vector b is [1]  2  3  4  5  6  0  1  1  7  8  9  0 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

Comment: Thank you. Henry. I updated the igraph package. But it still did not work. It seems the 0 in the membership vector b causes the problem. Is this a bug?

Comment: @Henry. I find the reason. Membership is a Numeric vector, for each vertex it gives its community. The communities are numbered from one, not zero.igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/modularity.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the same version of `igraph` as @Hnery

here my installed version of igraph   :

```
subset(as.data.frame(installed.packages()) , Package == 'igraph', select =c('Package','Version'))
       Package Version
igraph  igraph   0.6-3
```

It works when I replace the 0 in membership vector (b) like this :

```
 b[b==0] <- 1
> modularity(g,b)
[1] -0.04191321
```

I don't have the same result.

Comment: Thank you. @agstudy   It seems the 0 in the membership vector b causes the problem.

Comment: @user1933981 But  did you try read the other solution? do you have the same version?

Comment: I just updated the igraph package from 0.6-1 to 0.6-3. I find the reason. Membership is a Numeric vector, for each vertex it gives its community. The communities are numbered from one, not zero.http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/modularity.html

Comment: Normally that 's what is said in the help..maybe you need to contact the maintainer of the package..

Comment: Setting zeros to one will actually make the `modularity` function run, but it will give you the wrong answer. See my answer for the correct solution.